# How to write this function C

Tags: c, function

Hi I am new to C programming, I am just trying to replace part of my code with a function call but I don't know how to do it properly, please help.

I just want the line `d = ...` to be equivalent to the line `e = ...`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double dist(int i, int j, double v[100][2])
{
    return sqrt( pow((v[j][0] - v[i][0]),2) +  pow((v[j][1] - v[i][1]), 2) )
}

main()
{
    double v[100][2], d, e;

    v[1][0] = 0;
    v[1][1] = 1;

    v[2][0] = 1;
    v[2][1] = 1;

    d = sqrt( pow((v[1][0] - v[2][0]),2) +  pow((v[1][1] - v[2][1]), 2) );

    e = dist(1,2,v);

    printf("\n%f\n",d);
    printf("\n%f\n",e);
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having with the code you've written? Note that `main` is a function, so you already know the syntax of functions, to some degree. If you're in the process of learning the basic syntax of C, please do that through books, tutorials, classes, etc., not by asking bit-by-bit at SO.

Comment: Side Note: properly declare `main()` to return an `int` (don't rely on implicit return decl types) and properly return an actual value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
double dist(int i, int j, double (*v)[2])
{
    return sqrt( pow((v[j][0] - v[i][0]),2) +  pow((v[j][1] - v[i][1]), 2) ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

d = dist(0,1,v)

Or dist(1,0,v)

Distance between point 0 and point 1 ... Order does not matter.

EDIT: What I have above is a function CALL, as requested. d= is equivalent to e= ... to write another function is quite the waste of code and more importantly, not a realization of what a function is used for.  I stick by my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the same thing for different types, you *can* use a macro (not recommended for this case since a decent compiler will inline the function call to Cato's function) but just for educational purposes

```
#define dist(i,j,v) sqrt(pow((v[j][0]-v[i][0]),2)+pow((v[j][1]-v[i][1]),2))
```

Just keep in mind that sqrt returns a double, so if you want float or long double returns, you'll need sqrtf or sqrtl.

The advantage to using macros for mathematical "functions" is that they get expanded out into the code prior to compile such that constants can be evaluated into the computation and can sometimes reduce the entire calculation down to a much simpler computation or sometimes even a constant value.

Mike is correct on the mathematical properties, though precision may cause the 2 values to differ slightly (usually this difference is unwanted).

Comment: that depends on how you build your program, you don't _need_ to build modules at all: `gcc -O3 -pipe -combine -fwhole-program *.c -o myapp` ... but most complex code will initially fail with -fwhole-program unless the headers are tweaked

Comment: headers _normally_ have an #ifndef blabla #define blabla to avoid double inclusion, anyway compiling the entire program as a whole (see -lto, and you can do it still compiling separate modules) requires quite a lot more of memory and anyway it's not done by default.

Comment: @LtWorf My experience with -flto was that it did no better than compiling with -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections and linking with -Wl,--gc-sections but with significantly more overhead  (at least for dead code removal, inlines aren't as obvious to detect) but -fwhole-program beats them both (the thing with -fwhole-program headers is usually order-of-inclusion related)